# Nginx correct SSL Certificate order

Tags: nginx, ssl, https

I got the following files:

- priv.key // This is my priv key and contains one -----BEGIN ENCRYPTED
  PRIVATE KEY----- section
- req.csr // This is my certificate request file
- cert.pem // This is my certificate I got back per mail and contains one -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- section
- cacert_sha1.crt // this is the root CA I think
- chain.txt // dont know whats that for but must be usefull according to some tutorials :)

I tried a lot of stuff and combined the files in a lot of different ways to new .pem files. But I always get a not signed error from the browser when I surf to the website

I always restarted nginx after changing my config.

Does anyone knows how to combine in the correct order/way? Are this all files I need ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ssl_certificate_key` directive specifies your private key (that's your `priv.key` file).

The `ssl_certificate` directive specifies a file containing a concatenation of your signed certificate (which you call `cert.pem`), the Certificate Authority and zero or more chain files.

The certificate signing request is not used by `nginx`.

Care is required when concatenating the certificate files. Your certificate should be first. Also, there is a lot of extra junk in those chain files and I don't know if it gets ignored. You might want to edit the junk out.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_certificate) for more.

Comment: Ok you mean I have to combine cert.pem, cacert_sha1.crt, and chain.txt (without junk) ?

Comment: @Cracker0dks I suspect that the junk is ignored, but my files have no junk in them, so I cannot be sure. But yes - combine those three files.

Answer (score 3):

If got your SSL certificate from Comodo, here's the order the extra files should be combined in, presented as a `bash` command to do the job for you:

```
cat COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt \
COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt \
AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt>chain.crt;
```